# How to jump to next UITextField when editing has finished?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I want to inspect my current UITextField and jump to the next one in case that editing has finished.

So far I have this code implemented, but for some reason is not working.

**IMPORTANT:** The code that actually work as expected is Robert approach, see it below. I couldn't vote for him since my reputation is low.

**NEW ADDED:** I am using this to limit to ONE character

```
    //Limit the length of the UITextfields
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
    let newLength = text.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length

    print("textField...shouldChangeCharactersInRange method called")

    switch textField {
    case rateTvA:

        return newLength <= limitLength

    case rateTvB:

        return newLength <= limitLength

    case rateTvC:
        return newLength <= limitLength

        // Do not put constraints on any other text field in this view
        // that uses this class as its delegate.
    default:
        return true
    }

}
```

NOTE: I am expecting to receive just ONE single character for each UITextField

```
    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let charCount = textField.text!.characters.count
    print("textFieldShouldEndEditing method called")
    print("How many characters has been typed in? \(charCount)")

    switch textField {
    case rateTvA:
        if(charCount > 0) {
            rateTvB.becomeFirstResponder()
            return true
        }
    case rateTvB:
        if(charCount > 0) {
            rateTvC.becomeFirstResponder()
            return true
        }
    case rateTvC:
        if(charCount > 0) {
            rateTVD.becomeFirstResponder()
            return true
        }
    default:
        return false
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: have you added the delegate for UITextField?

Comment: it does not work, for some reason is not triggering your function, I just type in the character and it does not jump. Any idea what's going on? ---Please see my updated post where i include the code to limit the length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need depends upon what you want the user's experience to be.

1) You want to automatically jump to the next text field after the user has entered a single character. In this case you should use the Interface Builder to connect the text field's "Editing Changed" event to an IBAction method in your controller. That IBAction method should perform the first responder switching logic.

2) You want the user to take some action to indicate that editing has completed. That action's handler should then perform the first responder switching logic. I think that the return key is a good way to go. In this case you would use the TextField delegate's textFieldShouldReturn method.

Additionally, you should think about what you want to have happen if the user ends the editing of text field A by clicking in one of text fields B or C (or upon some other UI element that your are presenting); in which case your text field delegate's textFieldXXXXEndEditing methods will be called. The question is: should your textFieldXXXXEndEditing method switch the focus away from the element that the user has chosen?

Finally, you said that your code is not working. What is not working? Is the textFieldShouldEndEditing method not being called? If no then you might not be assigning to the text field's delegate property. Or, you might be confused about what causes the textFieldShouldEndEditing method to be called (my suggestions above should give you some clues).

Here is some code. The outlets should be connected using IB. Also, use IB to connect the Editing Changed event of each of the three text fields to the IBAction method.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var textFieldA: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldB: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldC: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    textFieldA.delegate = self
    textFieldB.delegate = self
    textFieldC.delegate = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    print("Should begin editing")
    return true;
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    print("Did begin editing")
}

func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    print("Should end editing")
    return true;
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    print("Did end editing")
}

func textFieldShouldClear(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    print("Should clear")
    return true;
}

func textFieldShouldChangeCharactersInRange(textField: UITextField, range: NSRange, replacement: String) -> Bool {
    print("Should change")
    return true;
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    print("User pressed return: switching to next text field")

    switchFields(textField)

    return true;
}

@IBAction func textChanged(textField: UITextField) {
    print("User entered a character; switching to next text field")

    switchFields(textField)
}

private func switchFields(textField: UITextField) {
    switch textField {
    case textFieldA:
        textFieldB.becomeFirstResponder()
    case textFieldB:
        textFieldC.becomeFirstResponder()
    case textFieldC:
        textFieldA.becomeFirstResponder()
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I really appreciate your explanation, but can you shade here some sample code? remember that I am asking this because I not a Swift Ninja.

Comment: Hi Carlos. I added code [it compiles and runs :-)]. Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Perfect!!! the code is working as expected ;-) thanks so much Robert. How I can vote for your response since I have few point?

Comment: That's great, Carlos. You, as the original poster, will have a way to mark my answer as the accepted answer (as opposed to up voting, which is a different thing). Do you see it?

Comment: Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably change the responder in the "textFieldDidEndEditing" delegate call. So take out the xxx.becomeFirstResponder() calls in "textFieldShouldEndEditing" and implement roughly:

```
optional func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

switch textField {
case rateTvA:
       rateTvB.becomeFirstResponder()
case rateTvB:
        rateTvC.becomeFirstResponder()
case rateTvC:
        rateTVD.becomeFirstResponder()
default:
    return
}
return
```

I haven't compiled this so beware.

Comment: it does not work, it is not jumping to the next field, see please my updated post where i include the function to limit the length size. everything is working fine except the it is not jumping to the next UITextfield.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to depend on a Third-party or any library you can follow below

### Use textfield delegate (Swift, Objective-c)

In Objective c you can do this:

```
-(BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    if (_verifyOTP.text.length >= 1 && range.length == 0)
    {
        [self.verifyOTP2 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    if(_verifyOTP2.text.length >= 1 && range.length == 0) {
        [_verifyOTP2 resignFirstResponder];
        [self.verifyOTP3 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    if (_verifyOTP3.text.length >= 1 && range.length == 0)
    {
        [_verifyOTP3 resignFirstResponder];
        [self.verifyOTP4 becomeFirstResponder];  
    }
    if (_verifyOTP4.text.length >= 1 && range.length == 0)
    {
        [self.verifyOTP4 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

In swift

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if (_verifyOTP.text.count >= 1 && range.length == 0)
    {
        self.verifyOTP2.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    if(_verifyOTP2.text.count >= 1 && range.length == 0) {
        _verifyOTP2.resignFirstResponder()
        self.verifyOTP3.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    if (_verifyOTP3.text.count >= 1 && range.length == 0)
    {
        _verifyOTP3.resignFirstResponder()
        self.verifyOTP4.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    if (_verifyOTP4.text.count >= 1 && range.length == 0)
    {
        self.verifyOTP4 becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    return true;
}
```

Else you can use PinView third party Library

[Pin view Github link](https://github.com/xornorik/SVPinView)